# What does "if [ -t 1 ]" do in shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, scripting

I have code for setting the zsh as default shell:

```
if [ -t 1 ]; then 
exec zsh 
fi
```

What exactly does the command `if [ -t 1 ]` do here?

Comment: 1st Google result: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389495/what-does-t-1-check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if command; then other_command; fi` runs `command` and then, if that command exits with a return code of 0 ("success"), runs `other_command`.

The command `[`...`]` is designed to take the place of the Boolean expressions that you find in traditional programming languages. It has a number of options for what goes between the brackets and exits with 0=success if those options evaluate to a true value.

The specific subcommand `-t` tests a file descriptor to see if it is attached to a terminal. The file descriptor 1 is where the script's output is going (aka "standard output" or "stdout" for short). So `-t 1` is true and `[ -t 1 ]` returns success if and only if the output of the script is going to a terminal (instead of into a file or pipe or something).

In that case, the current shell is replaced (via `exec`) by a copy of `zsh`. Which will hopefully not run the same script, since `zsh` works the same way and will make the same decision and go into an infinite loop `exec`ing itself.

Comment: should mention: the `[...]` is equivalent to the command `test`, and you can get all the possible options (`-n`, `-z`, `-t` ...) using `man test`

Answer (score 5):

> I have code for setting the zsh as default shell:

No, you haven't.  That's not what your code does, though it produces a similar effect.

> ```
> if [ -t 1 ]; then 
> exec zsh 
> fi
> ```
>
> What exactly does the command if [ -t 1 ] do here?

The command `[ -t 1 ]` is executed.  If it exits with status 0 (indicating success, which for the `[` command means the condition evaluates to true) then the commands in the body of the `if` statement are executed.

It may be a bit surprising that `[` is a command, rather than part of shell syntax, but that's the case.  Your `if` could be rewritten equivalently to use the `test` command instead:

```
if test -t 1; then
  # ...
```

The other key thing, then, is the `-t 1` part.  You can find out about that in the manual for the `test` or `[` command, but to save you the trouble, it is a conditional expression that evaluates whether file descriptor 1 (the shell's standard output) is connected to a terminal.  This is similar to, but not exactly the same thing as, evaluating whether the shell is an interactive one.

Overall, the code presented has the effect of replacing the current (presumably `bash`) shell with `zsh` if the standard output is connected to a terminal.  This is indirect, and a bit tricky; it would probably be better to genuinely set your login shell to `/bin/zsh` (or wherever it is installed) via the `chsh` command.